# python multiprocessing runs serial with certain parameters

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying run a set of code in parallel and it seems to work in some cases but not others. The code below runs in parallel with saved_models[item] is None or not present but runs very slow and in serially when it has data.

Any thoughts? The saved_model object is not that big and its different for every single run.
    from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
    def do_parallel_work(self):
        with mp.Pool(processes=self.max_workers) as pool:
            job_args = [(item
                         , target_col
                         , saved_models[item] if saved_models is not None and item in saved_models else None
                         ) for item in items]
            results = pool.map(self.do_work_helper, job_args)

```
        for result in results:
            if result[1] is not None:
                results_dict[result[0]] = result[1]

def do_work_helper(self, args):
    return self.do_work(*args)

def do_work(self, item, target_cols, saved_model):
    # can't show exactly what this but essentially it does something to the affect of:
    my_model = ARIMA()
    # if saved_model is None
    fit_model = my_model.fit(trend='nc', maxiter=1000, disp=0)
    # else
    my_model.predict()
    return item, stuff
```

Comment: You haven't shown how you call any of these functions.

Comment: I showed you how I call all of the functions except do_parallel_work, but I don't see how that is relevant. All the functions are part of a class. Made a small edit because I forget the "self" for the do_work function.

Comment: No you haven't. "Call" doesn't mean "give a name to", it means "make the code run inside the function". The code you've posted does absolutely nothing. You haven't called the functions.

Comment: OK, well you weren't very clear. How I call a function is not the same as what the function does. I have not show what the do_work function does. I can't show that exactly but i can provide more detail.

Comment: I don't believe I was unclear. "call" a function is the correct terminology; just like you'd call your friends and expect a response. The code inside a function body will not execute unless you call that function. It can be evaluated in terms of being syntactically correct, but it doesn't actually _do_ something to your data until it's called.

Comment: OK, its not clear to me what you need if anything to help. So if you do intend on helping let me know if I can provide any more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that I was doing this in a class and not all the functions were static. So it was copying the full class for each thread and I did not want this to happen. I believe just one sub function was not static which was forcing the entire class to get copied.